# Neo4j REST Cypher and params: what can be a parameter in a Cypher query through REST

Tags: rest, neo4j, cypher

I was trying the make this query work using params with no luck. I was always getting the same error.

```
expected either node or relationship here
"start n={start} match n-[r:{rel}]-() return n, n.name, r, r.since"
         ^
```

Then, I removed the `{start}` param and I used a backtip (`) for the relationship and it worked like a charm.

```
start n=node(*) match n-[r:`{rel}`]-() return n, n.name, r, r.since
```

So, what's the proper way to use params and where can I use them in a query?

Just in case, backtip the `{start}` doesn't work either. The next request doesn't work either.

```
POST /db/data/cypher {"query": "start n=node({start}) match n-[r:`{rel}`]-() return n, n.name, r, r.since", "params": {"start": "*", "rel": "l353456"}}
```

I'm using 1.9M01

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Backticking `start` (because start is a keyword) would look like this

```
POST /db/data/cypher {"query" : "start n=node({`start`}) return n", "params": {"start":0}}
```

Tested on the Neo4j Http console.

Comment: It seems there were two problems, one with `start` as a keyword, and another one with `*`. Try using this map as params ```POST /db/data/cypher {"query" : "start n=node({`start`}) return n", "params": {"start": "*"}}```

Comment: Javier, "*" is not supported as a parameter since it is not really a list of nodes. If you have * you don't need parameters since this should not be changing, and for sets of nodes you can use indexes?

Comment: I am creating a module to abstract Cypher syntax a bit in a few specific cases, and the idea was to provide the start of the query, that can be a list of nodes/relationships, and index with a query or the `*`. If the user doesn't set the start, `*` will be used. But OK, I will figure it out another way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Javier, http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/snapshot/cypher-parameters.html lists the patterns, so in your case I think

```
start n=({start}) match n-[r:XXX]-() return n, n.name, r, r.since
```

is what you can do. relationship types are considered as changing the structure of your query, and thus not parameterizable. You will have to re-submit the query or concatenate the query in your client code.

Comment: Then, this query should work?
    `POST /db/data/cypher {"query": "start n=({start}) match n-[r:`{rel}`]-() return n, n.name, r, r.since", "params": {"start": "*", "rel": "l353456"}}`
Because, unfortunately, it doesn't :(

Comment: And BTW, what about `ODER BY`? Can't I use params there?

Comment: I don't think so. Skip and Limit support parameters, though.